# Display UIImage within an array with custom class in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage, swift-array

I have a custom class *Product* defined as

```
class Product: NSObject {

var name: String
var priceLabel: String
var productImage: UIImage


init(name: String, priceLabel: String, productImage: UIImage) {
    self.name = name
    self.priceLabel = priceLabel
    self.productImage = productImage
    super.init()

   }
}
```

and I've created an array with that custom class

```
    let toy = [
    Product(name: "Car", priceLabel: "$5.00"),
    Product(name: "Train", priceLabel: "$2.50")
    ]
```

How would I insert the UIImage into that array? I would need to insert a different picture for each toy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few way to do it but with your code just example 1 will work:

```
// Example 1:
let toy = [
    Product(name: "Car", priceLabel: "$5.00", productImage:UIImage(named: "myImage.png")!),
    ...
    ]

// Example 2:
let product1 = Product(name: "Car", priceLabel: "$5.00")
product1.productImage = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")!
let toy = [
        product1,
        ...
        ]



// Example 3:
let toy = [
        Product(name: "Car", priceLabel: "$5.00"),
        ...
        ]
if let prod = toy[0] {
    prod.productImage = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")!
}
```

You have just one init which takes 3 parameters so if you create object like that:

```
Product(name: "Car", priceLabel: "$5.00")
```

it won't compile because you have not initialiser which accept just two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let newArray = toy.map{Product(name: $0.name, priceLabel: $0.priceLabel, productImage:UIImage(named: "myImage.png")!)}
```

side note: If you want to make your initialiser more dynamic use default parameters.

```
init(name: String = "DefaultName", priceLabel: String = "DefaultName", productImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "DefaultImage")) {
    self.name = name
    self.priceLabel = priceLabel
    self.productImage = productImage
    super.init()

   }
}
```